# Sorting a comma separated file

Tags: unix

How to sort a comma separated file (with following details) based on salary (ascending or descending)

```
a.Ename,firstname,lastname,salary
```

Answer (score 2):

`sort -t, -k4,4 filename`

That's for ascending, throw in -r for descending.

Comment: Probably going to want `-n` to make the sort numeric, and hopefully you salary numbers don't have commas in them :-)  If so, you should paste a few example lines (with names/numbers changed a little to protect the innocent.

Answer (score 1):

In my country the separator is not , but ; - so the solution is more complicated. Just in case this applies here too...:

```
LC_ALL=C 
export LC_ALL
```

and instead of -t, I use

```
--field-separator=\;
```